# Drop beam span beyond post

Tags: framing

I have an existing deck with sistered 2x12 drop beams and joists cantilevered over top.  The 2x12 current extend ~12" beyond the 'outside' post.  The span is significantly less than 12'.

We are considering extending the deck ~2'.  This would yield a beam that extends ~3' beyond the outermost post.

Lots of information exists specifying the extension of joints beyond the beam, but I am not seeing anything describing beam extension beyond a post.

Does anyone have experience with this or a specification?  Before doing anything I want to know if I'll be digging another footer...

Comment: Before addressing your structural design analysis concerns, more information is needed - type of wood, spacing of the beams, cantilevered one end or both ends.  Is your thought to replace the existing beams with longer beams? And. of course, realize that designing projects is beyond the scope of this site.  In this case there are not just practical considerations, but liability as well.

Comment: The most important question is are you extending the current beam and how?  But in general a 2x12 should handle a 3" extention beyond the last beam, going longer than that I would consider doubling the beam or putting in another support

Comment: This might fit in better over on DIY.SE.

Comment: The beam is a sistered 2x12 Doug fir  supported by 2 pressure treated 6x6s (notched). Span between these is ~6'. Joists are cantilevered to this beam and run into a stringer with joist hangers at the other end. I would replace this sistered beam with one that is 2' longer.  AWC offers guidelines for joists and I am wondering if something similar is available for beam specs. @bowlturner 3" or 3'?

Comment: @JayLaura I meant 3'.  I do that way too often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that it appears that a Douglas Fir 2" x 12" can span a 17' section being braced on both ends and 24" apart, you shouldn't have any problem with 1/4 of that hanging unsupported.  However, making a brace that supports part of the overhang with a 6"x 6" at 45 degrees could significantly improve the support.  so the cross beam might reach 2' out along the 4' overhang.  The span tables in the pdf below can help.

Many places actually need a deck plan approved and inspected after it is done to make sure it meets code.  At the very least they can be consulted beforehand to prevent any major issues.

http://www.msrlumber.org/spantables.pdf

Comment: You make a good argument for this question not being "solved" on the Woodworking site.  Getting this correct is not a matter of opinion and "it appears".  This is a safety and potential liability issue.  Professional involvement should come into play here.  You'll notice that OP's beams are doubled-up 2x12 spaced at 6'.  This would be effectively the same as single 2x12's spaced at 3'.  The tables to which you refer do not deal with 3' spacing for any loading condition.

Comment: Agreed re: approval and a deck plan.  Drafting these and looking to specs on the beam span (not the joist span as is so frequently documented).  Thanks for the linked pdf.